# How to run terminal commands from python script?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a ROS package that has dependencies on various python and ROS libraries. Is it possible to provide a script in python that can install conda, ros2 and other python packages? If possible could anyone please help me giving a template .py file on how I can install conda and other python packages using conda?

Comment: Have a look at the [`subprocess` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `os.system`:

```py
import os
cmd="""ls -l"""
os.system(cmd)
```

Comment: hello, I am trying to install ROS2 (https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Installation/Crystal/Linux-Install-Debians/). With os.system("xxx") everything works but not commands including CHOOSE_ROS_DISTRO (3 commands in the above link). Why is that?